# PlayerStats.Valid not return true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to get user status through google play services to make a daily rewards system for my game and I'm not getting the value back as true, my game connects to google play but I can not get the user's data. Here is the code snippet below

```
private string gameId = "3140248";
private bool testMode = true;

public List<Upgrades> upgrades = new List<Upgrades>();
public List<Area> areas = new List<Area>();

public Text Loading;
public GameObject ErrorGoogle;
public PlayerStats PlayerStats;

public void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("Connection");
}

IEnumerator Connection()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    PlayerStats = new PlayerStats();

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success == false)
        {
            ErrorGoogle.SetActive(true);
        }

        else if (PlayerStats.Valid)
        {
            Database();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1.Seems issue of wrong configuration or wrong calling of playerState valid.                      
2. Check valid method for that. Also, you can check the link below for this issue:                    
        https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/api/class/gpg/player